# Is Nunit ExpectedException Working Correctly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, nunit

I started having problems earlier when setting up some command line scripts to test my NUnit suite of tests for a project I am working on.

I noticed that when running the tests in `Visual Studio` or `Xamarin` that the results are what I expected, but when running from the command line with the `nunit-console` (mac `v2.4.8`) it doesn't fail some of the tests.

All the of the tests that are failing that don't fail in the console use the `[ExpectedException]` attribute (both with a type and in general). When changing to use `Assert.Throws<>` it works correctly in both the IDEs and the command line.

Is this a bug with Nunit or the particular version/platform I have?

Comment: The problem is mixing two testing frameworks - the attribute is a .NET out of the box test utility that NUnit does not understand. These tests pass when using the built-in VS test runner.
However, Nunit test runner will not pick up the meaning of the attributes.
Assert.Throws<> works with both runners because NUnit provides a VS plugin that augments the VS test runner to be compatible with NUnit.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Do the tests fail because no exception is thrown or because a different exception is thrown?

Comment: The tests **don't** throw. They carte-blanch pass when the attribute exists.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in `unit-console` 2.4.8 and has nothing to due with VS test runner as one commenter suggested. I use 3.x on the cmd-line to work around it by doing a local nuget install as I add this into my Makefile and can do a 'make test'.

#### Testing via 2.4.8 (and exposing the bug/issue):

> nunit-console -nologo -labels except.dll

```
***** except.Test.ExpectedException
***** except.Test.ExpectedNotSystemException
***** except.Test.ExpectedNotTypeOfSystemException
***** except.Test.NotExpectedException

Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Not run: 0, Time: 0.106 seconds

Test Case Failures:
1) except.Test.NotExpectedException : System.Exception : Stackoverflow
at except.Test.NotExpectedException () [0x00006] in /Users/sushi/code/XamTests/except/except/Test.cs:33
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch-c6sr1/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.2/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:295
```

#### Local 3.0.1 install and test (works correctly):

> nuget install nunit.runners
>
> ./NUnit.Console.3.0.1/tools/nunit3-console.exe except.dll

```
NUnit Console Runner 3.0.5813
~~~  
Errors and Failures

1) Failed : except.Test
One or more child tests had errors
2) Failed : except.Test.ExpectedNotSystemException
An unexpected exception type was thrown
3) Failed : except.Test.ExpectedNotTypeOfSystemException
An unexpected exception type was thrown
4) Error : except.Test.NotExpectedException

Test Run Summary
    Overall result: Failed
   Tests run: 4, Passed: 1, Errors: 1, Failures: 2, Inconclusive: 0
     Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Explicit: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2016-01-26 23:09:56Z
    End time: 2016-01-26 23:09:56Z
    Duration: 0.117 seconds
```

#### Test Case:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace except
{
    [TestFixture ()]
    public class Test
    {
        [Test ()]
        [ExpectedException]
        public void ExpectedException ()
        {
            throw new Exception ("Stackoverflow");
        }

        [Test ()]
        [ExpectedException("System.DivideByZeroException")]
        public void ExpectedNotSystemException ()
        {
            throw new Exception ("Stackoverflow");
        }

        [Test ()]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(DivideByZeroException))]
        public void ExpectedNotTypeOfSystemException ()
        {
            throw new Exception ("Stackoverflow");
        }

        [Test ()]
        public void NotExpectedException ()
        {
            throw new Exception ("Stackoverflow");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NUnit 2.4.8 is an antique!

Comment: But that is want is bundled with a Mono installation and within Xamarin Studio