# Mono Framework NUnit Version

Tags: xamarin, mono, sonarqube, nunit, sonar-runner

I'm currently running unit tests for a Xamarin application using the nunit-console (2.4.8) provided by the Mono Framework on OS X.

I'm trying to publish the results through SonarQube and I believe for this to work I need NUnit 2.5 or higher

Currently SonarQube errors because of a missing "errors" attribute in the xml results file, it seems like this got introduced in NUnit 2.5.

What options do I have for upgrading NUnit on OS X? Does any version of the Mono Framework support this higher version of NUnit? Can I get it as a separate binary?

Comment: I just `nuget install nunit.runners` in the base of the solution/project and `mono ./NUnit.Console.3.0.1/tools/nunit3-console.exe bin/Debug/yourtestassembly.dll` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019083/is-nunit-expectedexception-working-correctly/35025923#35025923 But you can always download the runner `.exe`, place it in some dir and update the `nunit-console` shell script to point to the newer assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All versions of NUnit are supported on Mono. There is no install package but you can get all the binaries as a zip.

Comment: I was able to get this working by downloading the binaries and using `exec mono nunit-console.exe <params>`