# While running the NUnit Test Cases through command prompt, Success Exception is thrown on MAC machine only. Any Solution to resolve it?

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin.mac, nunit-console

While running the NUnit Test Cases through command prompt, Success Exception is thrown on MAC machine only. All Test Cases are passing on Xamarin Studio. Even I am able to run all the NUnit Test Cases on Windows machine through IDE as well as CMD.

Command is -  nunit-console bin/Test.dll

Please find the below stack-trace for the same -

NUnit version 2.4.8
Copyright (C) 2002-2007 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment - 
   OS Version: Unix 15.5.0.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000 ( 4.6.0 (mono-4.6.0-branch/746756c Thu Sep  8 05:39:12 EDT 2016) )

...F.F.F...F..F.F.F...F.F.F..F.F.F

**Tests run: 21, Failures: 13, Not run: 0, Time: 83.483 seconds**

Test Case Failures:
1) Com.Tests.Api.ApiTest.TestInvalidXApiHeader : **NUnit.Framework.SuccessException** : Access token provided is invalid or has expired
at Com.Tests.Api.ApiTest.TestInvalidXApiHeader () [0x0003f] in <145cf86ff7fd46c1b4269832d7dbe00f>:0
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305

So Here I have written Test Case for Invalid Access Token. And one more things, it doesn't not give the details of number of test cases passes. Again I would like to mention that problem is only faced on MAC machine through CMD.

Comment: I would recommend trying the latest nunit/nunit-console when running from the shell as there are various bugs in that version, example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019083/is-nunit-expectedexception-working-correctly/35025923#35025923

Comment: Can you please tell me the way to install other stable version of nunit-console on MAC as NUnit version 2.4.8 is already bundled with mono ? Again I would like to mention there is no issues on windows machine. The mainly problem is with MAC machine through terminal.

Comment: You can use nuget to install a local copy, it is in the answer that i linked: `nuget install nunit.runners`, and then you run that version....

Comment: I haved installed nunit.runners through nuget package in Xamarin Studio. Now the question is how to run the test cases by taking the reference of this version through MAC terminal ? Please help me to so the same.